# Do we still need LiveData in Jetpack Compose, or we can just use Compose State?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

I have a ViewModel as below that has both LiveData and Compose State

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class SafeMutableLiveData<T: Any>(value: T) : LiveData<T>(value) {

    override fun getValue(): T = super.getValue() as T
    public override fun setValue(value: T) = super.setValue(value)
    public override fun postValue(value: T) = super.postValue(value)
}

class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val _liveData: SafeMutableLiveData<Int> = SafeMutableLiveData(0)
    val liveData: SafeMutableLiveData<Int> = _liveData

    var composeState: Int by mutableStateOf(0)

    fun triggerLiveData() {
        _liveData.value = _liveData.value + 1
        composeState++
    }
}
```

Both `composeState` and `liveData` above do the same thing and used by my Compose View as below

```
    @Composable
    fun MyComposeView(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
        val liveDataResult = viewModel.liveData.observeAsState()
        Column {

            Button(onClick = { viewModel.triggerLiveData() }) {
                Text(text = "Click Me!")
            }

            Text(text = "${viewModel.number} ${liveDataResult.value}")
        }
    }
```

I notice both the LiveData and Compose State values are

- Preserved when orientation change.
- Destroy when OnRestoration (app killed by the system).
- Don't update the compose view, i.e. when it's activity/fragment container no longer exists (e.g. won't crash the app like rxjava callback when the fragment/activity is gone).

It seems like `LiveData` doesn't add more benefit than `Compose State`. It has more complications like we need to add `.observeAsState()` etc.

Is there any scenario that we should still use `LiveData` instead of `Compose State` variable in our View Model when we program in Jetpack Compose only?

Comment: If you use `savedStateHandle.getLiveData()` inside ViewModel as Jetpack intends you to do, then this question is answered and solved

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, if I use `rememberSaveable` for the `ComposeState`, will that be the same now?

Comment: Technically yes, but at some point you will need something equivalent to `switchMap`. Maybe `snapshotFlow` can help with that, not sure. Or `by derivedStateOf`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce "...then this question is answered and solve." And that answer is...? Yes? No? Details how/why?

Comment: @KevinWorth they all do the same thing. I personally don't really trust `state.snapshotFlow {}` and also writing into State is not safe from a non-UI thread. So it's up to you really. Now you have support for `savedStateHandle.saveable` and `savedStateHandle.getStateFlow()`, making the barriers between type even less. But you are definitely not getting a `State<T>` from a Room DAO.

Comment: Hmm, still feels like a proper answer would be helpful, versus these small comments. Hopefully the bounty pays off.

Answer (score 1):

Both Compose's `MutableState` and Kotlin's `MutableStateFlow` may be used to replace `MutableLiveData` in a ViewModel.

If your `ViewModel` is supposed to be truly agnostic from the view system, then `StateFlow` is probably a better option than Compose's `State`. If you don't care about supporting other kinds of view systems than Compose, then you can use Compose's `State`.

**One important thing to consider though**, is that Compose's `State` is not **Lifecycle-aware** by itself. To make it Lifecycle-aware on Android, it is mandatory to use `LiveData.observeAsState()` or [`Flow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/consuming-flows-safely-in-jetpack-compose-cde014d0d5a3) from a composable function outside of the ViewModel. So if your state is connected to a data source performing active work while being observed, commonly called a "cold" flow, **then you must expose it as a `LiveData` or `StateFlow` from your ViewModel** and observe it in a Lifecycle-aware manner using these functions, otherwise the data source will continue performing work even when the screen is not visible.

Comment: This caveat is the one I've been worried about. If there are still hoops to jump through to avoid lifecycle gotchas, then it feels like LiveData might still be the easiest thing for that. Perhaps @BladeCoder you could add a snippet of "observing StateFlow in a lifecycle-aware manner"? Or perhaps at least an example of what not to do?

Comment: Or just keep your state variables in your ViewModel and dependency inject your data sources into it

Answer (score 0):

I see the next cases to use the LiveData still:

1. You are using ViewModel with a non-Compose View at the same time as with a Compose View. This is possible to face it in an old project which is under migration to Compose, for example, if you have a shared ViewModel for an old View and Compose View.
2. You have LiveData in other layers of the project. For example, you observe data from Room using LiveData.
3. You need to use a transformation API for LiveData `map`, `switchMap`, or other benefits.

But Google doesn't have strict requirements for which type of observable to use, it mostly depends on your project (requirements, architecture, etc.) and preferences. Google says apart from Compose State you can use LiveData, RxJava, Kotlin Flows, and just to convert it to State https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose

If we are saying about your example then I believe you don't need to use LiveData in such trivial cases.

In my opinion, looking at how Google actively promotes JetPack Compose and Kotlin Flows most likely that LiveData can be deprecated at some point in the near future.

Comment: @sergepetrov perhaps you can answer the following, and maybe put it into an edit of your answer. "If one's primary purpose in using LiveData is to take advantage of its awareness of lifecycle, then can one simply forgo LiveData because Compose/State is just as competent at being lifecycle aware?"

Comment: For instance, given you might choose LiveData instead of purely RxJava (so that you don't have to jump through hoops to make RxJava by itself lifecycle aware)... can one simply forgo LiveData because using Compose/State/Flow does not require jumping through similar hoops to make it lifecycle aware?